# KnownType related error with WCF serialization

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, serialization

**Background**

I have a client application that connects to a WCF backend. It calls a specific action and expects a very large object result.

When I attach the WCF code to w3wp (WCF is hosted on IIS), I get into the expected method call and the code runs all the way to the `Return result` line.

Doing a quick watch on the result reveals an object that, as far as I can humanly tell, matches exactly with my expectations. The fields that I expect to see filled in, contain logical values.

**The problem**

As soon as I skip beyond the `Return result` line, which is the very last that is called on the WCF call, I get this error:

> The thread 0x214c has exited with code 259 (0x103). 'w3wp.exe'

And deeper

> Type 'full.namespace.MyResultType' with data contract name
>   'MyResultType:' is not expected.  Consider using a
>   DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list
>   of known types - for example,  by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

**The question**

What do I do to solve this? As the error occurs within third-party code (I assume the WCF serialization process), I can't find out anything more than what I have (that I know).

Comment: Are you using inheritance in one of the classes in your object graph?

Comment: @Marc: A whole bunch of interfaces, not other classes.

Comment: This might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Try putting '<KnownType(GetType(MyResultType))> ' at the top of your base class....